# how to update(edit) upload files in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want make form edit for my upload files, so I want the file delete after the new file uploaded

this for my RazorView

```
﻿@model updownload.Models.updown
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.id)
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            @Html.ValidationMessage("uploadError")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.upload, new { type = "file", id = "file" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Username:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.keterangan)
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <button>Submit</button>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

and this for my Edit controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(updown viewModel, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        var currentupdown = db.updowns.Find(viewModel.id);

        if (viewModel.upload != null)
        {

            System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/upload"), viewModel.upload));

            string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/upload"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            viewModel.upload = fileName;

        }
        else
        {
            currentupdown.upload = currentupdown.upload;
        }


        currentupdown.keterangan = viewModel.keterangan;

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("List", "Home");
    }
```

I got error in this line `string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);`

can someone fix my code please.
sorry for my bad english

Comment: What is the type of `upload` ?

Comment: `string` @Shyju

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a typical null reference exception because `file` is `NULL` and you are trying to access the `FileName` property on that.

**Why is file null ?**

For file upload to work from a form, the form should have `enctype` attribute with value set to `"multipart/form-data"`. Your current view code will generate the form tag without that.

```
<form action="/Home/Edit" method="post">     
</form>
```

So first fix that.Also, for the file uploading to work, your file input element's name attribute value must match with the name of your `HttpPostedFileBase` parameter.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
                                           new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
      @Html.LabelFor(a => a.keterangan)
      @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.keterangan)

      @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.id)

      <input type="file" name="file"/>
      <input value="submit" type="submit" class="btn" />
}
```

This will render the correct HTML markup needed to send the file.

Now in the server action method, you need to d a null check on the `file` parameter before trying to access that.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(updown viewModel, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var currentupdown = db.updowns.Find(viewModel.id);

    if (file != null)
    {
       var location=Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/upload");

        //Delete existing file
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentupdown.upload))
       {
           var existingFile= Path.Combine(location, currentupdown.upload);
           if (System.IO.File.Exists(existingFile))
           {
               System.IO.File.Delete(existingFile);
           }
       }

       var fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
       var path = Path.Combine(location, fileName);
       file.SaveAs(path);
       currentupdown.upload = fileName;   // Update to the new file name
    }

    currentupdown.keterangan = viewModel.keterangan;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("List", "Home");
}
```

Since you have a view model, you can also add a new property to the viewmodel called `File` (of type `HttpPostedFileBase`) and simply use that in your server action. With this you can remove the second parameter as your view model already has a property for this. So instead of checking `if(file!=null)`, you would be doing `if(viewmodel.File!=null)`

```
public class YourViewModel
{
  public int Id { set;get;}
  public string Keterangan { set;get;}
  public HttpPostedFileBase File { set;get;}
}
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(YourViewModel viewModel)
{
   // use viewModel.File as needed
}
```